# hasOwnProperty.call(A, B) と A.hasOwnProperty(B)

Tags: javascript

```
hasOwnProperty.call(A, B)
```

・どういう意味でしょうか？
・下記と同じ？？

```
A.hasOwnProperty(B)
```

---

hasOwnProperty上書きの件で、質問追記します。

・for文と組合せた下記のような記述をよく見かけるのですが、

```
for (var key in obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
         console.log(key + ":" + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

・「当初質問した内容の両者」が同じなら、Function.prototype.call()を使用した方が良いのではないかと思うのですが…

```
for (var key in obj ) {
    if ( hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key) ) {
         console.log(key + ":" + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

・Function.prototype.call()をあまり見かけないのは、hasOwnPropertyが上書きされることなどない、という前提に立っているからでしょうか？
・そこまで考慮する必要はないってこと？

Comment: 同じと考えて良いと思います。[Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

はい、基本的には同じです。

ただし、`A.hasOwnProperty = null;` 等とメソッドが上書きされていた場合、前者は正常に動作し、後者はランタイム エラーになります。

---

オブジェクトが持つキーを自分でコントロールできるのであれば、`.call()`は使わなくて良いでしょう。できない場合 (例えばユーザー入力をキーにする) は、そのプロパティを信用できないので `.call()` 呼び出しのほうが良いです。この場合、他にも考慮すべきことがあって、例えば `__proto__` が上書きされるとプロトタイプチェーンが変化して予期せぬ挙動の原因になる可能性があります。

なお、性能的には `.call()` 呼び出しのほうが若干悪いです。